# Optimizing mysql slow query

Tags: mysql, optimization

below query taking more than 2.5 seconds running from 20lacs records;

```
SELECT lid,nid ,sum(nview) as view_cnt 
FROM nv 
WHERE  lid = 1 
GROUP BY nid
ORDER BY view_cnt desc 
LIMIT 20;
```

i updated the possible key as indexes, Please help me to optimize this query

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys    key        key_len ref      rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      nv      ref     lid              lid        4       const    406282  "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort"
```

Comment: run `SHOW CREATE TABLE view_cnt` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ..(yourquery)..` and include the results in your question.

Comment: Your `ORDER BY` clause also seems suspicious, you probably want to `ORDER BY view_cnt` instead?

Comment: i give the EXPLAIN FOR SELECT query updated above

Comment: @romain: again im having problem with order by clause

Comment: How many different `nid` are there for a `lid` on average? The `ORDER BY` clause requires the `filesort` operation, which is super-slow, if you have too many rows to sort.

Comment: it has more than 100 or less for each nid and the table total records 20lacs

Comment: it has more than 100 or less for each nid and the table total records 20lacs

Comment: How many rows does this query return?

Comment: Had to google hard to find out how many is 20 lacs, it's not really understandable in regions other than south asia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding an index on all columns used in the query:

```
ALTER TABLE nv ADD INDEX lnv(lid,nid,nview)
```

so that mysql uses column values from the index instead of using index only for the row lookups. You should see additional `using index` in your explain extra column. It can probably speed up your query a bit, but don't expect a lot, filesort in this case is unavoidable without changing the table schema.

If you decide to use this index you can safely remove index on single `lid` column as the composite one can be used for lid lookups as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have indexed only lid column, can you add index to nid column and verify the query execution time

Comment: i have updated index for nid then i give the EXPLAIN again the same result only displaying , nid doesn't display in possible keys column